# Clean URL to Stack Overflow account for external linking

Tags: support, user-accounts, hyperlinks

Is it possible to get a nice-looking URL to a Stack Overflow user account for external linking?

This is to include a link to my Stack Overflow account in a [CV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curriculum_vitae) or in a blog.

For example, [LinkedIn](http://linkedin.com) provides URLs in the form of

```
http://<country>.linkedin.com/in/<username>
```

Is a similar URL available for a Stack Overflow account? I noticed that the URL to my Stack Overflow account has a number in it. Is this something like a user id. For example, will it ever change or am I safe to use that as external link as in the following?

```
http://stackoverflow.com/users/<somenumber>/<username>
```

Comment: That number isn't "something like a user id" - it *is* your user id.

Comment: The URL to your profile page is not going to change as long as you retain the same account. The number is your user ID, which is the unique way of identifying you. The username is not important at all and gets ignored. You can link to anything as the username, for example, clicking this link will take you to your Meta profile page, despite the fact that it replaces your username with a little phrase: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/140169/whats-in-a-name. Also, this is a duplicate (see iammichael's answer, below).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it make sense now, I searched a bit around but couldn't find this information anywhere (the other linked question has the answer but it's never been upvoted so it's lost at the bottom of the page ...)

Answer (score 0):

Consider making yourself a customized [Bitly](http://bit.ly) or [TinyURL](http://tinyurl.com) to point to your Stack Overflow URL.