# How do we get a perma-link to a user profile which does not change when they change their profile name?

Tags: support, profile-page, network-profile, internal-links

Suppose that a user of stackexchange changes their username from `PurpleKiwi` to `FuchsiaCucumber`

How do we get a permanent link to their user-profile which is still valid after the name change?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we have a profile URL?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22044/can-we-have-a-profile-url) Especially, [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22058/348196).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clean url to SO account for external linking?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32494/clean-url-to-so-account-for-external-linking) - the number is necessary because not all names are unique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just copy the URL from your address bar.

This is yours: https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/610179/samuel-muldoon

Note what happens when you replace that name with that of an infamous user: https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/610179/glorfindel - it still links to your profile and automatically redirects to the right one.

Finally, there's a short form available of RobertLongson's one: https://meta.stackexchange.com/u/610179. You might need this one if you'd otherwise hit the maximum comment or chat message length.

Answer (score 5):

Just use their id, that stays the same no matter what the display name. For instance yours is:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/610179